# Spectral radii and norms of similar elements in a C*-algebra: $\|bab^{-1}\|<1$ if $b=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a^*)^n a^n)^{1/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a\in A$ such that $r(a) < 1$. Define b  = $(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a^*)^n a^n)^{1/2}$. We can prove that $b\geq e$ and that $b$ is invertible.
I want to show $\| b a b^{-1} \| < 1$.

From the definition of $b$ we see that
$a^* b^2 a = b^2-e$ and we know $r(bab^{-1}) = r(a) <1$.

So it suffices to prove $r(b a b^{-1}) = \| b a b^{-1} \|$. It can follow from the fact $c = ba b^{-1}$ is a normal element... I don't know how to prove it (I have tried to compare $c^* c$ and $c c^*$...).

---

Context: The question appears in Murphy's book, page 74.   I have managed to prove the first part. The second part of the question is to prove
$$r(a)= \inf_{c\in Inv(A)}\{\|cac^{-1} \| \}$$
It's easy to see $$r(a) \leq \inf_{c\in Inv(A)}\{\|cac^{-1} \| \}$$
But I can't prove $$r(a) \geq \inf_{c\in Inv(A)}\{\|cac^{-1} \| \}$$ If we have had $r(a) = \|b a b^{-1} \|$ then it was obvious... But this is not true, so how we can prove this inequality?

Comment: (Jonas is right, btw.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I think this question is one of the exercises in Murphy's book on $C^\ast$-algebras

Comment: If this question has been taken from Murphy's book, then this should be acknowledged in the question. Likewise if this forms part of an exercise set or other homework.

Comment: $r(bab^{-1})$ is not typically $\|bab^{-1}\|$ (e.g. take $a$ nilpotent); $c=bab^{-1}$ is not typically normal.  But $c^*c$ is a good thing to consider: it simplifies considerably, and using $b\geq e$ allows you to show that $\|c^*c\|<1$.

Comment: @YemonChoi:Thanks.

Comment: Jonas, Thanks for the hint. If we know only $\|b a b^{-1} \| < 1 $ and not $\|b a b^{-1} \| < r(a)$ I don't understand how to solve the second part of the question: $r(a)= \inf_{c\in Inv(A)}\{\|cac^{-1} \| \}$. how can I prove the inequality $r(a) \geq \inf_{c\in Inv(A)}\{\|cac^{-1} \| \}$ ?

Comment: Yes, The question appears in Murphy's book - page 74. link: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/152/murphy.png/

Comment: colge: Thanks for providing the source.  Some notes on your first comment:  (1) You didn't ask about showing anything about infs.  If you wanted to ask about that, it should be included in your question. (2) You do not want to show that $\|bab^{-1}\|<r(a)$; that would in fact contradict what the second part of the problem asks you to show.

Comment: Jonas, I have just edited the question.

Comment: colge: It seems $r(a)=0$ should be treated as a special case.  If $r(a)>0$, consider applying the first part to $\frac{1-\varepsilon}{r(a)}a$.

Answer (score 2):

The first part can be solved by simplifying $(bab^{-1})^*bab^{-1}$ to show that it has norm less than $1$, using the fact that $b\geq 1$.  (In particular, $a^*b^2a$ simplifies nicely.)

The second part can be solved, in the case when $r(a)>0$, by applying the first part to $\frac{1-\varepsilon}{r(a)}a$, yielding for $0<\varepsilon<1$ an invertible $b$ such that $\|bab^{-1}\|\leq\frac{r(a)}{1-\varepsilon}$.  The case when $r(a)=0$ can then be solved by applying the previous case to $a+\varepsilon e$ and using the inequality $\|x+y\|\geq \|x\|-\|y\|$.

Comment: Could you give a hint on the simplification? I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: @LSK21: After putting not much thought in it years later, I guess I had in mind the fact that it simplifies to $b^2-e$, and perhaps hadn't noticed that was already mentioned in the question. If it requires more thought than that, I probably won't be able to help.