# For what operators $A$ on a Hilbert space is the identity operator in the closure of the similarity orbit of $A$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

For a bounded linear operator $A$ on a separable Hilbert space, the similarity orbit of $A$ is the set $S(A)=\{WAW^{-1}: W \text{ is invertible}\}$. I am wondering that if the identity operator $I$ is in the closure of $S(A)$, what can we say about $A$?

I looked here [References on similarity orbits of operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163762/references-on-similarity-orbits-of-operators), which lead me to the article "The Closure of the Similarity Orbit an a Hilbert Space Operator" by Apostol, Herrero and Voiculescu. In the article they classify $\overline{S(A)}$, but it is very complicated, and I was hoping that with a seemingly simpler question asking

for which $A$ is $I\in \overline{S(A)}$

would be more tractable. I understand that this is a not so specific question, so to perhaps provide more detail, I am interested in how large the set of operators $\{A: I\in \overline{S(A)}\}$ is. Is it norm dense? SOT dense? etc.

Any examples or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The set of invertible operators is open, the set of non-invertible ones closed. So a necessary assumption is that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: With a similar argument, one can show that $\sigma (A)\subset \{1\}$ is necessary. In the complex case, this implies $\sigma (A)= \{1\}$ and in particular $\Vert A\Vert \geq 1$, so that the set will not be norm dense.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to come up with an easy example, like $A=P+I$, where $P$ is a finite rank orthogonal projection. This allows me to try and come up with $\{W_n\}$ such that $||W_nPW_n^{-1}||\rightarrow 0$, which is easier for me to think about.  However, all the $W_n$ I cook up are just wieghted permutations of an orthonormal basis, which if picked correctly can make $W_nPW_n^{-1}\rightarrow 0$ pointwise but not in norm.

Comment: I suppose $||W_nPW_n^{-1}||$ can never approach $0$ since $W_nPW_n^{-1}$ is a projection, so $\sigma(W_nPW_n^{-1})=\{0,1\}\not \subset \{0\}=\sigma(0)$.