# Norm of similar elements in $C^{*}$-algebra - Murphy

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, spectral-radius

I have a question concerning exercise 6 in chapter 2 of Murphy's $C^*$-algebras and Operator Theory. The exercise is as follows:

Let A be a unital $ C^* $-algebra. If $r(a) < 1$ and $b = (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a^*)^n a^n)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, show that $b \geq 1$ and $\|bab^{-1}\| < 1$.

So, I have been able to prove that $b$ is greater than 1, but I am having trouble with the second part. A hint was given here: [Spectral radii and norms of similar elements in a C*-algebra: $\|bab^{-1}\|<1$ if $b=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a^*)^n a^n)^{1/2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140676)

I tried simplifying $(bab^{-1})^*bab^{-1}$ as suggested, but have not been able to make any progress. I can see that $a^*b^2a$ simplifies to $b^2$, but I cannot make the connection to the rest. Any more help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: Correction to the last paragraph, $a^*b^2a$ simplifies to $b^2-1$.

Comment: "I can see that $a^\ast b^2 a$ simplifies to $b^2$" - then look again. There is an index shift.

Comment: @MaoWao True, the sum then starts at $n=1$. I still don't see the connection though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, $a^*b^2a=b^2-1$. Then
$$
\|bab^{-1}\|^2=\|(bab^{-1})^*bab^{-1}\|=\|b^{-1}a^*b^2ab^{-1}\|
=\|b^{-1}(b^2-1)b^{-1}\|=\|1-b^{-2}\|.
$$
The element $b^{-2}$ is positive, and since $b\geq1$, we get that $b^{-2}\leq 1$. Then $0\leq 1-b^{-2}\leq1$, which implies that $\|1-b^{-2}\|\leq 1$. But we can say a bit more. Since $b\geq1$, we know that $\sigma(b)\subset [1,\beta]$ for some $\beta\geq1$. Then $\sigma(1-b^{-2})\subset \big[0,1-\frac1{\beta^2}\big]$. Thus
$$
\|bab^{-1}\|^2=\|1-b^{-2}\|=1-\frac1{\beta^2}<1. 
$$

Comment: Should the first norm be squared in the last line?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for noticing.